# table collapse (rows hide) not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, hide

```
function tablecollapse()
{

    var table = document.getElementById(tblbatting);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=4; i< rowCount; i++) 
    {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        row.display="none";
    }
}
```

I have this code running `onload()` but the table's connect aren't hiding.
What is wrong with this code? or any other suggestions?

Comment: This is not a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Wayne said. He was a lot faster than me.

```js
function tablecollapse(id) {

  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var rows = table.rows;

  for (var i = 4; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>five</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<button onclick="tablecollapse('foo')">Collapse</button>
```

Comment: Hi Will, I don't know what I was doing wrong before. But I did everything again now based on your code, and it worked. Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the code.  First, you need to put quotes around the table element id in `var table = document.getElementById(tblbatting);`.  So, this code becomes `var table = document.getElementById("tblbatting");`.

Second, to set the display style, you need to access the style property of the table row element.  So `row.display="none";` becomes `row.style.display="none";`.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tblbatting");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var i=4; i< rowCount; i++) 
{
    var row = table.rows[i];
    row.style.display="none";
}
```

I am not sure if you have done it deliberately or not, but you should be aware that your code will not hide the first 4 rows of the table because you have used `var i=4` to initialise your loop counter.

Comment: Hi Wayne. Yes, I have kept the first four rows visible on purpose. And I corrected those errors and it still isn't working, Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: I have created a fiddle using Will's code above, and it is working as I think you desire.  https://jsfiddle.net/1eL7tvhr/1/

Comment: That code works perfectly fine. But when I am implementing it same way, its not working at all.

Comment: Can you post the html for your table.  The problem may be in the html.

Comment: <body><div class="divhead">
 <img src="images/cricket-banner.jpg" height=100% width=100%>
 </img>
 </div>
 <button onclick="tablecollapse('tblbatting')">Collapse</button>
 <div class="divscore">
 <table id="tblbatting" cellspacing="1px">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" align="right"><p class="score" ><b>India 100/1</b> vs Australia</p><td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td colspan="7" align="center">Overs 14.5</td></tr>
 <tr id="titlerow">
 <td><b></b></td><td><b>Batsmen</b></td><td><b>Runs</b></td><td title="Balls Faced"><b>Balls</b></td> <td><b>4s</b></td><td><b>6s</b></td><td><b>S.R</b></td>
 </tr>

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5PwZCo3q5gUWhDUTM4YjAtWU0/view?usp=sharing

Check this link to the file.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the HTML?  The comment truncates it.

Comment: CSS for the same 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5PwZCo3q5gQjFrTnRJQkktc0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hope you have checked the links. I have made some changes after seeing Will's code. So it probably looks bad.